# Does chromium keep logs of the events leading up to opening a new tab?

Tags: logging, chromium

I had a tab randomly open up that was for adware.  Luckily, it was caught by my ad blocker, but I would like to figure out what triggered it to open.

I tried checking its history state through console, but I found nothing interesting.  I tried checking a few suspect pages, but I hadn't been recording network activity on them so there was no history.

**Does chromium keep logs of the events leading up to opening a new tab?**  Can I figure out what page/plugin/daemon tried to open up this tab?

I did find this similar question which implies (by absence of suggestion) that no such logging exists, but it does not state so explicitly: [How to determine which Chrome extension is re-directing me to ad sites](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/273853/how-to-determine-which-chrome-extension-is-re-directing-me-to-ad-sites)